# Is it possible to run Spring boot 2.x on Jboss EAP 6.4.x?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss6.x

Is it possible to run Spring boot 2.x on Jboss EAP 6.4.x?
After deploying I can't reach the service.

I get 404 when trying to reach the service.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If logs says that appstarted than it is fine. You probably try to reach in on wrong app context like localhost:8080/yourapplicationname/some/test/service - while you probably ommit `yourapplicationname`part. But anyway - closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already answer to my question.
You can't use Spring boot 2 with Jboss 6.x because Spring Boot is build on Spring 5 and Spring 5 does not support Servlet 3.0 which is used in Jboss 6.x.

Spring 5 supports Servlet 3.1 and above